# Installing gdal to use with topo json and D3

Tags: javascript, json, windows, gdal

I am working on a map tutorial (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) focused on using gdal, topojson, and D3.  The tutorial I am following focuses on a mac.  I have to work with a PC.

Downloaded gdal from this site (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) and followed the instructions for windows.  As far as the d3 and topojson I have those packages installed properly in my project directory.  How do I go about installing gdal on a windows so I can convert the data from it to topojson using Gitbash as my command prompt?

Thank you, 
Greg

Comment: To convert from shp to topojson, npm topojson is enough in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install GDAL on Windows is using the [OSGEO4W Installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

Just use the "Advanced" option and you can choose GDAL from "Commandline_Utilities"-"gdal". The installer also enables you to have multiple GDAL versions side by side, should you ever need that.